# Segfault when dereferencing void ** arguments

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm lacking understanding of pointers here. **foo1** is a pointer of type **foo**. In dequeue, there are a list of items of type **foo** that are dynamically allocated passed in by queueList. My mission is to get **foo1** to point to the head of the queue, however, accessing the **foo1** pointer that was passed into **dequeue()** with ***data** causes a segfault. Here is where I lack understanding. Is ***data** not referring to the **foo1** pointer?

```
struct foo
{
//Properties Here
};

int main()
{
    struct foo* foo1;
    dequeue(myQueueList, (void*) foo1);
}

void dequeue(struct queue* queueList, void **data)
{
    *data = NULL; //Causes Seg fault if I do this too
    *data = queueList->head->data; //Seg fault if I do this as well
    return;
}
```

My queue is defined as:

```
struct queue
{
    node * head;
    //other stuff
};

struct node
{
    void * data;
    //other stuff
};
```

Edit: foo1 is not initialized in main. I want to initialize it in dequeue by setting it equal to a different struct foo* pointer that's been enqueued.

Edit2: queue holds a list of struct foo* pointers.

Edit3: Thanks to wildplasser, it's fixed with (void*)foo1 -> (void*)&foo1. But why do I have to use &foo1 and not (void*)?

Comment: `dequeue(myQueueList, (void*) foo1);` -->>  `dequeue(myQueueList, &foo1);` Also: your *foo1 pointer is pointing nowhere; there is no foo object that it points to, and it is not NULL.

Comment: @wildplasser why is NULL needed for foo1 when foo1 gets initialized in dequeue? What I want is foo1 to point to another foo type in heap. Or am I thinking of this the wrong way?

I want the equivalent of:

struct foo* foo1 = queueList->head->data;

where data is a void* type.

Comment: is `queueList->head->data` a `struct foo*` type masquerading as a `void*`?

Comment: In this case it would not be needed. But the dequeue routine *could* do things differently (such as deallocate, or not allocate at all) when not NULL. Uninitialised data is (generally) just a bad habit. Ald returning the pointer **as a return value** would not need any pointer to pointer at all.

Comment: `data` is an uninitialized pointer, so you can't dereference it. Duh.

Comment: @yano yes. **queueList->head->data** is just a pointer to other **struct foo** objects. 

The thing is calling ***data = NULL** itself causes a segfault.

Comment: @TommySaechao because `data` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @immibis How would I initialize it in the dequeue function?

Comment: It did! But changing it to &foo1 causes compiler warnings for incompatible pointer type.

Comment: which compiler are you using and what's it's version?

Comment: I'm using

**gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609**

Comment: casting &foo1 to (void*)&foo1 fixes the warning. 

@wildplasser

So why do I have to use &foo1 and not (void*)?

Comment: You may want to rethink your whole architecture. Using `void*` should be avoided as well as casting away compiler warnings. At best you lose compiler type-safety checking, which will inevitably lead to hard-to-track-down bugs later. If your queue holds a list of `struct foo*` pointers then why go back and forth between `struct foo*` and `void*`?

Comment: @yano I agree with you. Using void* is a really terrible when there is only one type. However, it's required for this assignment I'm working on for Operating Systems and we had to implement a generic queue data structure.

Comment: @TommySaechao They are better way to do this look how linux implement his linked list.

Comment: @TommySaechao Well by writing `data = &something;` of course. But it would make more sense in your program for the caller to pass an initialized pointer.

Comment: I changed it to initialize to NULL. Would it be better if I used malloc to initialize it? Wouldn't this cause a memory leak if all dequeue does is change the pointer to point somewhere else?

Comment: @wildplasser `dequeue(myQueueList, &foo1)` is a type mismatch (and hiding the error with a cast just leads to silent undefined behaviour instead)

Comment: Ok, then add the cast : `dequeue(myQueueList, (void **) &foo1);`

Comment: @wildplasser undefined behaviour

Comment: See my comment 51 mins ago: use the return value, luke!

Comment: @wildplasser, returning a pointer would not need a void ** indeed. That would have been my preference. But unfortunately for me, we had to write our queue off of his the professor's file and we cannot modify his header file.

@wildplasser `(void**)&foo1` compiles fine with no errors. What would be the difference beteween casting `foo1` as `(void**)&foo1` vs `(void*)&foo1`. How will my dequeue function see the argument?

Comment: Well: the function *expects* a `void **`. So to comply with the function's signature you'll need to give it a `void **`. And, *semantically*, after dereference, the function expects to get a `foo*`.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
struct foo* foo1;
dequeue(myQueueList, (void*) foo1);
```

the expression `(void *)foo1` causes undefined behaviour, because you use the value of an uninitialized pointer.

The concept of what you wanted to do was to pass the *address of* `foo1` to the function, so that the function can modify `foo1`.  You need the `&` operator to find the address of things.

However the function does not know anything about a `struct foo *`.  `void **` is not a generic pointer type; it is a pointer to exactly a `void *` and nothing else.  So to make this code work without changing the definition of `dequeue`, you need to make a `void *` variable:

```
void *vfoo;
dequeue(myQueueList, &vfoo);
struct foo *foo1 = vfoo;
```

It would be easier to use `dequeue` if you could change its design; in particular, have it return `void *`. Then you could write `struct foo *foo1 = dequeue(myQueueList);`.

Note: In comments it was suggested to use `dequeue(myQueueList, (void **)&vfoo);`, however this will cause undefined behaviour due to a strict aliasing violation. Object of type `struct foo *` cannot be accessed via an lvalue of type `void *`.

Comment: I see, so I just want to clarify. Passing in `(void*) foo1` for arg2 is equivalent to passing `*foo1` if foo1 was a void type?

And when I pass `&foo1' I am passing the `ADDRESS` of the `POINTER` which can be de-referenced into a pointer by using `*data` inside my `dequeue` function.

And for `struct foo *foo1 = vfoo;` Why would we not type cast `vfoo` to (struct foo*)vfoo if we do it this way? 

I agree it would be easier to use dequeue if we change the design, but I was provided a header file by my professor, which we are not allowed to change for this assignment.

Comment: What kind of undefined behavior would casting `foo1` to `(void*)` or `(void**)` cause? And how does `dequeue()` see foo1 in `(void **)&foo1` versus `(void*) &foo1` when passed for arg2?

Comment: @TommySaechao Re. the second comment, I explain this in my answer. Using the value of an uninitialized pointer causes undefined behaviour. Casting a pointer uses its value.   `(void *)&foo1` and `(void **)&foo1` , as function argument, have the same effect since the function prototype ensures that the former is converted to the latter

Comment: Re. the first comment, `(void *)foo1` is not equivalent to `*foo1`.  `foo1` is a variable. `(void *)foo1` means to convert the value of the variable to `void *`.   `*foo1` would indicate the object which `foo1` is pointing to.   `&foo1` is the address of `foo1`, which is a pointer. You could write `(struct foo *)vfoo` but it is good practice to avoid redundant casts.